# How can i dynamically change images as Background in TailwindCSS?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to make a carousel, where the background is changing, i don't want to use the `<img/>` tag! I set the value as described in the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values

My Code:

```
import React from 'react';

type CarouselProps = {
  img: string;
};

const Carousel = ({ img }: CarouselProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`col-span-full bg-[url(${img})] bg-cover grid grid-cols-12 gap-6`}
    > ...
    </div>
);
};
```

When i set the String i pass to the Component hardcoded it works but when i use curly Braces and $ it doesn't. In addition i don't want to define my Background-Images in the `tailwind.conf.js`

The Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5]
.use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!
./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css) 9:36-70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i don't want to define my Background-Images in the tailwind.conf.js

Well you have to. What you're trying to do isn't supported.

> The way Tailwind scans your source code for classes is intentionally
> very simple — we don’t actually parse or execute any of your code in
> the language it’s written in, we just use regular expressions to
> extract every string that could possibly be a class name.

so tailwind has no idea what your React code actually means. So it's simply not going to work.

---

[Tailwind does not support dynamic class names:](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

> Don't construct class names dynamically
>
> ```
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```

you should [customise your theme](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#customizing-your-theme) to include the image url:

> You can add your own background images by editing the
> theme.backgroundImage section of your tailwind.config.js file:
>
> tailwind.config.js
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   theme: {
>     extend: {
>       backgroundImage: {
>         'hero-pattern': "url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')",
>         'footer-texture': "url('/img/footer-texture.png')",
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I can do so, but I have a CMS as backend and I am not really sure how to import these images to the Tailwind config. Is it possible to make the tailwindconfig async?

Comment: No it's not. You simply can't do this with tailwind. You'll need to use standard CSS instead, which should be simple to do, just using the `style` property?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the `style` attribute. Thanks for helping :)

```
<div
      className="col-span-full bg- bg-cover grid grid-cols-12 gap-6"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${img})`,
      }}
    >
```